# grok pattern to custom logstash config

Tags: filtering, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

```
^(?:%{LOGLEVEL:level}):\s*%{DATA:message}\s*(?:%{JAVACLASS:caller_class})\s+\[%{WORD:loglevel}\]\s+(\[\s*\S+\s+%{BASE10NUM:tstamp}.*?\]\s+)+(\[\s*\S+\s+%{BASE10NUM:memory}\S*\s+\S+\s+%{BASE10NUM:total}.*?\])
```

this is my grok pattern from here https://regex101.com/r/yMq9J1/1

and now I wanted to use this in my logstash config in filter but I get an error

> The given configuration is invalid. Reason: Expected one of #, => at line 12, column 19 (byte 341) after filter {
>     grok {
>       match => { "message" => "^(?:%{LOGLEVEL:level}):\s*%{DATA:message}\s*(?:%{JAVACLASS:caller_class})\s+[%{WORD:loglevel}]\s+([\s*\S+\s+%{BASE10NUM:tstamp}.*?]\s+)+([\s*\S+\s+%{BASE10NUM:memory}\S*\s+\S+\s+%{BASE10NUM:total}.*?])"
>       }
>   }
>   output {
>       elasticsearch

can you guys help me understand the situation here?

Comment: Can you post your whole configuration, please? It would us seeing where the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

The grok pattern is not the problem, the configuration is missing a `}` to close the match setting of the grok filter.

It should be added after `%{BASE10NUM:total}.*?])"`, like this:

```
      ...%{BASE10NUM:total}.*?])" 
    }  # missing accolade
  } 
}   

output { 
  elasticsearch
  ...
```

Comment: input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "^(?:%{LOGLEVEL:level}):\s*%{DATA:message}\s*(?:%{JAVACLASS:caller_class})\s+\[%{WORD:loglevel}\]\s+(\[\s*\S+\s+%{BASE10NUM:tstamp}.*?\]\s+)+(\[\s*\S+\s+%{BASE10NUM:memory}\S*\s+\S+\s+%{BASE10NUM:total}.*?\])"
        }
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch 
    {
     hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
     template_overwrite => true
    }
}

Comment: @DeepakMann There is an edit button below the tag in your question that you can use to change your question to add such information, which has no place in comments.

Comment: @DeepakMann This configuration worked without problem on my computer (LS 2.2 on Windows 7).